# Bind array of dictionaries to nstableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsdictionary, nstableview

----EDITED----

My situation: I have a cell-based `NSTableView`. In this tableview there are 3 `NSColums`, 1 is a image box, one is a text box and the third is a checkbox. 
I have an array controller, that is beeing populated with the following code:

```
    [imgArrayController addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName]], @"image", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName], @"filename", [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES], @"check1", nil]];
```

But this code is not working properly. i know from various tests that this code is not working, its adding rows, but they are empty. its 4 days i am searching for this solution now without any luck.

Thanks

Comment: Buddy please ask question in short and elaborate way So that someone find interest to answer you. I tried to answer you but your question is unclear to me.

Comment: thanks for taking time to answer. ok my problem is that i need to add rows at runtime to a table. i do it with the long code i posted. in the NSTableview the rows appear, but they are blank, no content is displayed. and i think that the error is somewhere in the code i posted because the binding to the table is something i have already done in the past. its 3 days i am trying to fix this without success.. thanks!

Comment: Try to add '[imgArrayController rearrangeObjects]' and '[tableView reloadData]'. If this won't help check the bindings.

Comment: thanks, tried but none of those solved. do i need to initialize the mutabledictionary somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure that your image part is correct.. try this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *imgdtl = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSImage *myimage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName]];        
    [imgdtl setObject: myimage forKey: @"image"];
    [imgdtl setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,fileName] forKey: @"filename"];
    [imgdtl setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"check1"];
    [imgArrayController addObject:[imgdtl copy]];
```